# how to remove one leading and trailing single quote(') from a string in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need some help removing 1 leading and 1 trailing single quote from my string in Postgres 14.

string is

```
'''alter table test add column col2 int[] default ''''{}'''' not null'''
```

desired output:

```
''alter table test add column col2 int[] default ''''{}'''' not null''
```

I've tried trim but it removes the quotes from around the curly brackets as well.

```
=# select trim('''alter table test add column col2 int[] default ''''{}'''' not null''');
                              btrim
------------------------------------------------------------------
 'alter table test add column col2 int[] default ''{}'' not null'
```

Comment: `trim` is definitely not removing quotes from the middle of your string. Please show us your code.

Comment: Thanks. `trim` is doing nothing here; you haven't even told it which character to remove. Doubled quotes within a string _literal_ become one quote in the string itself. For example, `SELECT ''''` will return `'`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use a regex replacement here:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '^''|''$', '', 'g') AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

Notes:

- A literal single quote in a SQL string is represented by *two* single quotes.
- The regex pattern `^''|''$` matches a single quote at the start or end of the string.
- We use the `g` 4th parameter to do a global replacement.

Comment: This is also removing the single quotes around the curly brackets. `ALTER STATEMENT: '''alter table test add column col2 int[] default ''''{}'''' not null;'''
Regex ALTER STATEMENT: 'alter table test add column col2 int[] default ''{}'' not null;'`

Comment: No it's not....

Comment: my desired output needs to have 4 single quotes on each side of the curly bracket, 2 single quotes before `alter`, and 2 after `;` at the end

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TRIM('''' FROM your_string) FROM your_table_name;
```

Note that there are four single quotes. By putting two single quotes inside, one escape the other.